# There is no certificate chain in portal certificate file

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

I am trying to install Mcafee EMM in a lab environment. I have created an enterprise CA and created a certificate. But while installing the EMM, its showing the error of

```
there is no certificate chain in portal certificate file
```

What is this error and how to rectify it? I have googled but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your CA provider for a new certificate with the full keychain otherwise you won´t be able to use your certificate with EMM. 
But actually I have trouble with my 2048bit cert with EMM 9.6 . With my old 1024bit cert everything works fine. But you can also use a self signed vert, then your devices only ask if they should trust the cert. . It´s not the best solution but for testing OK.